# Is it possible to change the layout/fonts of google forms using HTML in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently working with google forms and there's a requirement to change the layout and font of google forms. I am aware of creating HTML forms using HTML and programming in google apps script but using Google forms is part of the requirement.

Can you please let me know if it's feasible using HTML with Google forms to change the layout of Google forms?

Any pointers in the right direction will be helpful.

Comment: Check [this post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/google-forms-customize-colors-images-and-fonts/) out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737951/google-form-embed-style-and-change-thankyou-page/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657894/generate-own-html-for-google-form

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462740/how-to-create-custom-theme-for-google-form

Comment: Thank you both for the links. I have found out that it is not possible to customise the look/feel of google forms using HTML/CSS and keep the google forms id/url, the url will change and they will be required to be hosted elsewhere.